# Creating a class object with a different variable in a while loop

Tags: java

I am pretty new to java so I understand my code will not be very good. However I am trying to create a new class object using a while loop which will have the like 1,2,3 etc as a variable and then in that it will have the games name after pulling it from a website.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class GameInformationPuller
{
    public static void PullInformation() {

        String gameName = "";
        String gameRating = "";
        String gameGenre = "";
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        GameInformation name;
        boolean flag;


        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.mmorpg.com/gamelist.cfm/show/all/sCol/titleUC/sOrder/asc");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\data4.txt"));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                if(line.contains("http://www.mmorpg.com/gamelist.cfm/game/") || line.contains("<span class=\"value rating\">") || line.contains("title=\"Not enough votes to tabulate\">") || line.contains("<td class=\"genre\">"))
                {
                    if(!line.contains("Jump to Random Game"))
                    {
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length()); 
                        //------------------------------------------------
                        if(line.contains("http://www.mmorpg.com/gamelist.cfm/game/"))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            count = 0;
                            i = 0;

                            while(i < line.length() - 1 && flag == false)
                            {
                                if(count >= 2 && flag == false)
                                {
                                    if(line.charAt(i) == '<')
                                    {
                                        flag = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if(!(line.charAt(i) == '.'))
                                        {
                                            sb.append(line.charAt(i));
                                            gameName = new String(sb);                      
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if(line.charAt(i) == '>')                           
                                {
                                    count++;
                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        //------------------------------------------------                                  
                        name = new GameInformation(gameName);
                    }

                    //------------------------------------------------              
                }
                else
                {
                    //Nothing
                }
            }



        }  

        //Close reader and writer
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I want a new variable for each game name it finds at this part:
name = new GameInformation(gameName);
Hope this makes sense.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: It's not answering your question but I suggest you have a look at [jaunt](http://jaunt-api.com/) if you want to scrape a website for information.

Comment: Just a syntax trick: `flag == false` is pretty uncommon, `!flag` is shorter to write (and, my opinion, more readable) :)

Comment: Ill remember in the future these tips :) I guess im still used to the old VB ways lol

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of Java collections, for example `ArrayList`. Just define the `name` as:

```
ArrayList<GameInformation> name; //or names makes more sense
```

and later use it like this:

```
name.add(new GameInformation(gameName));
```